# Angular Universal Home page load issue

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I created an angular 6 app, but due to SEO issue I converted the Application in angular universal.
All content is loading fine, but when I load the url to check the website, it's keep on loading and no content showing..
On the home page content is loading from API calls which are connected with mysql database.

When I commented the API data it's loading fine.

Can anyone suggest how to load API calls on the home page when the page loaded first time with API call?

If there is any other way, please let me know...

I am stuck from last 3 days and no success...

Comment: Are your API calls being made at all? Have you read: https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/docs/gotchas.md ?

Comment: yes its working fine.. in simple angular 6 it was fine, but when i load content dynamically as its loading in angular 6 its not loading API calls on page load.. please let me know how to make call on angular home page.

Comment: Universal *should* make the API calls twice, once on the server-side and once on the client, unless you use state transfer. Sounds like there is another issue which is preventing your API calls from being made, or your state isn't being transferred from the server-side to the client correctly.

Comment: Okay i will follow this service state transfer and update you...

Comment: @Brandon thanks for suggestions, there was one module which was creating issue, so we fixed that and now site is working fine..

Comment: Awesome. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally my issue is being resolved. In one component, there was a code which was creating an issue while loading content, which is now fixed according to angular universal.

Comment: hey man, i had the same problem. Which was the code that was failing? How do you detect it? The error is silent so i have no clue

Comment: fixed, i had a setInterval :D